# How to list all distribution groups with name, grouptype, managedby, and AD description

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a list of all distribution groups with name, grouptype, managedby, and AD description.

```
get-distributiongroup  | select-object name, GroupType, managedby, @{Name="Description";expression={get-qadgroup $_.name | select-object description}}
```

This works for the most part, but the description column returns the object, not just the description.  How do I get this to only return the description using powershell with QAD and exchange snapins (if needed)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're using Select-Object which outputs the group object, you can get the Description property directly if you put the Get-QADGroup call in parenthesis:

```
Get-DistributionGroup | 
Select-Object Name,GroupType,ManagedBy,@{Name="Description";Expression={(Get-QADGroup $_.Name).Description}}
```